# How does PKCE help public clients?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pkce

According to https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/how-does-pkce-prevent-authorization-code-interception-attacks#why-use-pkce?

> The attacker can then use the stolen code to request an access token
> from the token endpoint, impersonating the legitimate client. This is
> especially risky for public clients, which are applications    that
> cannot store a client secret securely, such as native or single-page
> applications.

If the attacker has control over the user in a way that can prevent use of the authorization code, what's to stop them from obtaining the PKCE challenge too?

They obviously have complete control over the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCE is there to ensure that it is the same client(application) that does both the initial authenticaton request and the request with the authorization code.

For example, in mobile apps or browser extensions, if a "evil" app gets the authorization code, then it should not be able to use it.

[image]

The problem is that multiple apps might try to register for the same redirect_uri in a mobile phone for example.

How can a hacker capture the redirect?

Mobile applications often register a custom scheme to receive the redirect request back from the STS:

```
app-name://?access_token=??????
```

For example:

```
com.googleusercontent.apps.123504760640ip7qq628i6dreavptfk981d9ji6x:/oauth2callback
com.googleusercontent.apps.5996697-7obf9q7equ9msfakdcg8iveqgn3sck1s:/oauth2callback
fb19884028963vimeo://authorize/fb1592193007691679://authorize/
x-msauth-azureiosapp://com.microsoft.azure
ms-whiteboard-iosauth://com.microsoft.whiteboard
mevo://vimeooauth
oreilly://oauth/complete
```

What if the hacker also registers the same scheme?

The clientID, the hacker can easilly by capturing a sample request from a mobile application.

Comment: Doesn't the inability of a bad app to get the client secret mean that if the bad app got a hold of the auth code, it'd be useless since the bad app needs the client secret too?
How does PKCE add any security here?

Comment: I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ot45WwQWJE and it seems as though it's not about making sure it's the same app, it's about binding a code challenge to the auth code so that a bad actor can't inject the auth code in his own oauth flow.

Comment: Hes, tying the auth code to the initial authentication request. Also, PKCE is validated on the Identity provider side, compared to the nonce and state that is validated on the client side.  There's cases of clients that fails to validate the state/nonce properly, so PKCE adds an extra layer of protection here.  Feel free to accept my answer or let me know what is missing.

Comment: I think the bit I found confusing was "ensure that it is the same client". It doesn't ensure it's the same client because it'd be impossible for it to be a different client because it'd be a different clientID which wouldn't work right? I think if the answer said "it binds the auth code to the initial request" it'd be accurate.

Unless you can show an example of how an auth code injection attack would work without PKCE and with two different clients?

Answer (score 0):

when user logins, we create a challenge

```
import pkce from 'pkce-gen';

const challenge = pkce.create();
console.log('challnge', challenge);

// challnge {
  code_verifier: 'wM8w-unbwmv5UWNWxV3dftSLxEPVKJaoKC7bEPE0cOw',
  code_challenge: '2mMkAfg2efGKAA16b-0AXCPi7ISG6D6FWM_cbEc9ODo'
}
```

when we make the first request to oauth server we pass the `code_challenge`

```
code_challenge_method: 'S256',
code_challenge: challenge.code_challenge
```

the oauth server hashes this and resend it back to redirect url  in the url as parameter. so in your callback api route

```
const code = url.searchParams.get('code') || null;
```

The code verifier is transformed (usually by using a hashing method) to create a code challenge, which is sent along with the authorization request.

Now client makes a POST request to the authorization server passing the code and the original `challenge.code_verifier` which is created in previous step.  The authorization server checks if this code verifier matches the one used to create the code challenge.

As you see, with PKCE, this intercepted code alone is not enough to get tokens. The genuine client application also needs to provide the original code verifier during the token exchange. Without this verifier, the server won't grant access.