# How does using PKCE with the authorization code grant type improve the security of confidential clients in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth

For OAuth 2.1, using PKCE is recommended even for the authorization code grant type to prevent authorization code injection attacks.

However, assuming the attacker can already intercept responses and read cookies (for example, using a malicious browser extension), can't they already steal session cookies, rendering PKCE pointless? I'm not sure what kind of attacks it prevents that `state` and client password doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500795/how-does-pkce-help-public-clients/77502605#77502605

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks, but your answer only applies to public clients (and specifically for mobile apps), and it doesn't really answer why it's recommended for confidential clients

Answer (score 2):

I think this section in the [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-2.1.1-2.2) summarizes it nicely (and it's a good reference to keep in your back pocket):

> For confidential clients, the use of PKCE [RFC7636] is RECOMMENDED, as
> it provides a strong protection against misuse and injection of
> authorization codes as described in Section 4.5.3.1 and, as a
> side-effect, prevents CSRF even in presence of strong attackers as
> described in Section 4.7.1.

Where PKCE is essentially an extra protection against a malicious actor getting a hold of the authz code or swapping it out with one they have. PKCE provides additional protection by requiring to not just have the authz code but **also** the `code_verifier` in order to trade the authz code for a token. That's regardless of the client being public or confidential.

The second part of that section mentions the "side-effect", a bonus, is that you also get protection against CSRF attacks where typically you're using nonce or state to provide the protection. If you're using PKCE, it's redundant to create a separate CSRF token.

---

The OAuth 2.1 spec says it's REQUIRED to protect against authz code injection attacks ***unless*** both of these things are true:

> To prevent injection of authorization codes into the client, using code_challenge and code_verifier is REQUIRED for clients, and authorization servers MUST enforce their use, unless both of the following criteria are met:
>
> 1. The client is a confidential client.
> 2. In the specific deployment and the specific request, there is reasonable assurance by the authorization server that the client implements the OpenID Connect nonce mechanism properly.
>    In this case, using and enforcing code_challenge and code_verifier is still RECOMMENDED.

And they mention its usefulness in [protecting against CSRF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-09#name-cross-site-request-forgery):

> The traditional countermeasure is that clients pass a random value,
> also known as a CSRF Token, in the state parameter that links the
> request to the redirect URI to the user agent session as described.
> This countermeasure is described in detail in [RFC6819], Section
> 5.3.5. The same protection is provided by the code_verifier parameter or the OpenID Connect nonce value.

This is saying the same thing as above.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling PKCE for confidential clients might seem like an overkill.

Just as the title of the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) says, PKCE is mainly for public clients.

However, the OAuth 2.1 [specification](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-07.html) says

> Historic note: Although PKCE [RFC7636] (where the code_challenge and
> code_verifier parameters were created) was originally designed as a
> mechanism to protect native apps, this advice applies to all kinds of
> OAuth clients, including web applications and other **confidential
> clients.**

So, why is adding PKCE for cofidential clients still a good idea?

One reason is that it has been found that many client library implemntations fails to properly verify the nonce/state, leaving the clients vulnerable. While PKCE is verified on the authorization server, meaning that even if the clients does not properly (or fail to) verify the state/nonce, then PKCE will still protect them.

Comment: Should add a source for your claim that many libraries haven't been properly implemented. But, still, **even if** it's been properly implemented, it's still beneficial. The CSRF protection is a consequence of how it works. The target of PKCE was to ensure the client that received the authz code is the same client making the exchange for the access token and it's the intended code (it hasn't been unknowingly swapped). That's how it got its name **P**roof **K**ey for **C**ode **E**xchange). Using `nonce` or `state` do not provide such protection.